# Scipy.stats.entropy is giving a different result to entropy formula

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to calculate the information entropy of a probability distribution, but I'm getting 2 different answers and I don't know why or which is correct.

1. I tried using scipy.stats.entropy.
2. I then looked at the source code for scipy.stats.entropy, and as in the source code, I calculated entropy using scipy.special.entr, and got a different answer.
3. I then calculated entropy using purely the formula given on the scipy.stats.entropy page, and got the same answer as 2.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import entr
from scipy.stats import entropy
np.random.seed(123)

data = np.random.rand(5)

e = entropy(data,base=2)          #this one is different, why?
f = np.sum(entr(data))/np.log(2)
g = -np.sum(data*np.log2(data))
```

Any idea where the error is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`entropy` automatically normalizes the input so that the sum of the probability vector is 1.  Your calculations for `f` and `g` do not.

If you normalize `data`, e.g.,

```
data = np.random.rand(5)
data /= data.sum()
```

the results will agree:

```
In [35]: data = np.random.rand(5)                                                            

In [36]: data /= data.sum()                                                                  

In [37]: entropy(data, base=2)                                                               
Out[37]: 2.2295987226926375

In [38]: np.sum(entr(data))/np.log(2)                                                        
Out[38]: 2.2295987226926375

In [39]: -np.sum(data*np.log2(data))                                                         
Out[39]: 2.2295987226926375
```